# Improving performance of complex logical conditions on numpy arrays

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, logic

I need to evaluate many logical conditions on a large 2D "NUMPY" array, and collect the overall result in a boolean "RESULT" numpy array.

A simple example where all conditions are linked with an AND statement could be:

RESULT= cond1(NUMPY) & cond2(NUMPY) & cond3(NUMPY) & ....

I would like to understand if there is a way to optimize performance.

For example in this case, if the first condition (cond1) is False for most of the values in the NUMPY array it will be a waste of resources evaluating all other conditions on those values since the AND conditions will anyway generate a False in the final RESULT array.

Any ideas?

Comment: Python `and` and `or` short circuit, but only for scalar conditions.  With whole `numpy` whole-array operations, each condition is evaluated, and then the values are combined.  You'd have to use `numba` or `cython` to construct a faster iterative test that implements short-circuiting.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and suggestion, I am not so familiar with numba and cython yet, but I will look into those if I do not find another way :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the short-circuiting by hand, though I should add that this is probably only worth it in rather extreme cases.

Here is an example of 99 chained logical ands. The short circuiting is done either using the `where` keyword or using fancy indexing. The second but not the first gives a decent speed up for this example.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.random((1000,))*1.5
c = np.random.random((100, 1))*1.5

def direct():
    return ((a+c) < np.arccos(np.cos(a+c)*0.99)).all(0)

def trickya():
    out = np.ones(a.shape, '?')
    for ci in c:
        np.logical_and(out, np.less(np.add(a, ci, where=out), np.arccos(np.multiply(np.cos(np.add(a, ci, where=out), where=out), 0.99, where=out), where=out), where=out), out=out, where=out)
    return out

def trickyb():
    idx, = np.where((a+c[0]) < np.arccos(np.cos(a+c[0])*0.99))
    for ci in c[1:]:
        idx = idx[(a[idx]+ci) < np.arccos(np.cos(a[idx]+ci)*0.99)]
    out = np.zeros(a.shape, '?')
    out[idx] = True
    return out

assert (direct()==trickya()).all()
assert (direct()==trickyb()).all()

from timeit import timeit

print('direct  ', timeit(direct, number=100))
print('where kw', timeit(trickya, number=100))
print('indexing', timeit(trickyb, number=100))
```

Sample run:

```
direct   0.49512664100620896
where kw 0.494946873979643
indexing 0.17760096595156938
```

Comment: Very interesting! I will try and have a look if I can use a similar way to speed up my code :).  Thank you!